# xfce4 mouse switches workspace

Tags: xfce

I am running linux mint 16 with xfce. I don't know what exactly happend, but the workspace gets switched to another as the mouse moves through screen edge. This is quite annoying!

Is there any setting I can fix to restore to normal behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Settings" then to "Window Manager Tweaks" then to "workspaces". Choose "Use the mouse wheel on the desktop to switch workspaces"

Answer (score 1):

Open `Settings Manager/Window Manager/Advanced` and unselect `Wrap workspaces when the pointer reaches the screen edge: with the mouse pointer`.